# Что это за кнопка?

Tags: java, android, ui, android-button

Подскажите, что это за кнопка? Как она называется? И как такую сделать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это **switch button**.

[Пример реализации](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-switch-button-example.html).

По ссылке:

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Switch Button Example" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Android Switch Button 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Switch Button" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Android Switch Button 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Switch Button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="ViralAndroid.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch switchButton, switchButton2;
    TextView textView, textView2;
    String switchOn = "Switch is ON";
    String switchOff = "Switch is OFF";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.switch_button_example);

        // For first switch button
        switchButton = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        switchButton.setChecked(true);
        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean bChecked) {
                if (bChecked) {
                    textView.setText(switchOn);
                } else {
                    textView.setText(switchOff);
                }
            }
        });

        if (switchButton.isChecked()) {
            textView.setText(switchOn);
        } else {
            textView.setText(switchOff);
        }

        // for second switch button
        switchButton2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchButton2);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        switchButton2.setChecked(false);
        switchButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean bChecked) {
                if (bChecked) {
                    textView2.setText(switchOn);
                } else {
                    textView2.setText(switchOff);
                }
            }
        });

        if (switchButton2.isChecked()) {
            textView2.setText(switchOn);
        } else {
            textView2.setText(switchOff);
        }
    }    
}
```

Как будет выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]